# .val() JQuery. Passing text fields to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, textfield

Basically my code is perfectly fine it is I just cant seem to be able to get the extra added tags when I create them to have any functionality with the api search. I want to pass them into the tags field aswell as $("#textbox1").val(). Any tips/help is appreciated. Thanks

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   
       
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#images").empty();



        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
            {
                tags:$("#textbox1").val(),
                tagmode: "any",
                format: "json"
            }, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                    


                    $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                    if(i==2) return false;
                });
        });
    
    });
    $('#images').on('click', 'img', function(){
        
    });
});


    $(document).ready(function(){

     var counter = 2;
  
     $("#addButton").click(function () {
    
    
   
   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label></label>' +
    '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
    '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
            
   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    
      counter++;
     });

  
  $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
  
   var msg = '';
   for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
    msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
   }
      alert(msg);
  });
  
  });
        
       
</script>    
<button type="button" id="button">Find image</button>

    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
        <input type='button' value='Add tag' id='addButton'/>
 </div>
</div>


    <div id="images"  /> </div>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great to see this question back. I worked quite a bit on it and then posted it 12 seconds before you deleted it

Comment: Thank you!, never seen it lol. Great to see feedback!

Answer (score 1):

1. please format your code
2. Please have only one ready
3. use a class

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
      $("#images").empty();
      var tags = [];
      $(".textbox").each(function() {
        tags.push(this.value);
      });
      console.log(tags)
      $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
        tags: tags.join(" "),
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
      }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
          $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
          if (i == 2) return false;
        });
      });
    });
    $('#images').on('click', 'img', function() {
    });

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function() {
      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
      newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label></label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="textbox" name="textbox' + counter +
        '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      counter++;
    });
    $("#getButtonValue").click(function() {
      var msg = '';
      for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
        msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
      }
      alert(msg);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="button">Find image</button>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <input type='textbox' class="textbox" id='textbox1'>
    <input type='button' value='Add tag' id='addButton' />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="images" /></div>
```